# Minimizing clustering classification error

Tags: algorithm, classification, cluster-analysis, permutation

Suppose we've some labeled data X with N data points. Using some clustering algorithm, say k-means, we partition X into k clusters C_1,...,C_k. Let S_1,...,S_k be the true partitioning sets and define the clustering classification error like this: [image: error like this]

I want to then find the optimal "match" of the clusters to the true clusters by minimizing this error. So for k=3 the optimal permutation may be {(C_1 and S_2), (C_2 and S_3), (C_3 and S_1)}. The obvious way to find the optimal permutation would be to look at all k! permutations and the resulting error, and pick the one giving smallest error. This however requires k! time so my question is, would it be possible to design an algorithm to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good and well-tested algorithms for finding the best matching, such as the

[Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

But usually, it is not a good idea to map clusters to classes.

A good clustering is one that tells you something *new* about your data. So it *must* be substantially different grom your known classes.